# Rails 4 custom method in Model with no Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have 3 relevant models in a Rails 4 app - Charge:

```
class Charge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rate
  belongs_to :shift

  def total
    self.rate.value * self.quantity
  end

end
```

Rate:

```
class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :charges
end
```

and Shift:

```
class Shift < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :charges

  def total_charge
    self.charges.sum('total')
  end

end
```

I'm attempting to use shift.total_charge in my view, but I'm getting the error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: total: SELECT SUM(total) FROM "charges" WHERE "charges"."shift_id" = ?
```

So it seems that it isn't possible to define total in the Charge model in this way, and have it accessible to sum from the Shift model as an actual column would be. I'm struggling to find the appropriate Rails 4 way of doing this - is it possible to do this in the model, or do I need to create a controller for Charge and try to do the calculation there?

Comment: In which table you have the column `total` ?

Comment: I don't have a column `total` - it's the method in the Charge model.

Comment: O i see, overlooked..

Comment: try `Shift.joins(charges: :rate).where("shifts.id = ?", shift_id).sum("rates.value * charges.quantity")` .. Let me know if it works ..

Comment: In which model? Please list as an answer so I can mark correct if it works.

Comment: You try it in Rails console to see if it works... If it work, then I will think in which model to put it. First try it in the console.

Comment: You could just do this with ruby rather than sql by making `total_charges`: `self.charges.map(&:total).inject(:+)`.

Comment: @Joseph SQL is fast most of the time instead of in-memory ..

Comment: @Joseph your version in the Ruby console gives `SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting end-of-input
total_charges: self.charges.map(&:total).inject(:+)`

Comment: @Joseph's solution sounds correct. If you just write that line i.e. `self.charges.map(&:total).inject(:+)` in the `total_charge` method in Shift it should work.

Comment: @HO what Joseph meant was replace the body of the total_charges method e.g. `def total_charges;self.charges.map(&:total).inject(:+);end` he did not mean copy the whole thing.

Comment: have you tried adding: attr_accessor :total to Charge.rb

Comment: Make Joseph's recommendation more efficient with `self.charges.pluck(:total).inject(:+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum` works only with columns. You could use something like

```
class Shift < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :charges

  def total_charge
    self.charges.map {|c| c.rate.value * c.quantity }.sum
  end
end
```

and to avoid n+1 problem include `Rate` in `Charge`

```
class Charge < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :rate
  belongs_to :shift

  default_scope {includes :rate}
end
```